# Best way to model my classes?

Tags: google-app-engine

What will be more efficient?

Have a large kind with a one property to filter

or

Have a large kind and in another kind has a propertylist with keys and use second kind to recover entities belong to first kind.  Aprox 6k items per list.

options 1 ***_*__*_*__**

```
class customer()
  propertyinteger
  propertystriing
  ...
  propertyintegerID = use to be filtered and indexed
    thousand of costumers
```

option 2 ***_*__*_*____**

```
class customer()
  propertyinteger
  propertystriing

class CustomerGroup()
    propertystring
    propettycustomerList (repeated=True) (save a list with __key__ of customer class)
```

And I use CustomerGroup ListProperty to get only customer that i am interested. The list will have 6k aprox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is probably fine.  If I understand you correctly, each customer can belong to a group, a customer can only belong to one group at a time, and you want to be able to query for all customers that belong in a group.  Your group query is just an equality filter on a single property of the Customer kind.

There are other considerations with regard to your needs for consistency guarantees and the queries.  Assuming two Customer entities must be in separate entity groups, the index for the group ID property would be updated with eventual consistency, so a new Customer or a change in group ID may not appear as a result for the group query until shortly after the update.  If that's not OK, option 2, or a set of separate customer-to-group pairing entities in the same entity group, would make the group query (with ancestor filter) strongly consistent with updates.  Option 1 could be made strongly consistent by putting all Customer entities in the same group, but that has potential disadvantages, depending on the needs of your app.